# htaccess to modify URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the urls:

```
http://example.com/at
and want to get:
http://example.com/at/index.php?at=

http://example.com/at/
and want to get:
http://example.com/at/index.php?at=

http://example.com/at/1asSde
and want to get:
http://example.com/at/index.php?at=1asSde
```

Also I am modifying the .htaccess located at the folder 'at'

I've been trying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?at=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but am getting errors later when running the script of the site.

What can I try instead in order to get the correct results?

Thanks.

Comment: you're missing a rewrite condition

Comment: Have you tried printing out `$_GET['at']`?

Comment: I removed the php tag on this question, since the use of PHP doesn't factor in.

Comment: I get what I expected in $_GET['at']. But later I get errors like: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html.

Comment: also, I am modifying the script in /at/.htaccess. So, there is no need to handle 'at'

Comment: decided to remove the folder and make it a global declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^at/(.*)$ at/index.php?at=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You don't need a rule for `at` so long as `at/index.php` is a *physical* location. I would encourage you to create a better match for `at`. For example change `(.*)` to `(\w+)` if it can only be alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^at/(.*)$ /at/index.php?at=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^at/(.*)$ index.php?at=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure that the resource you're trying to get doesn't exist before rewriting the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?at=$1 [QSA, L] #didn't test to make sure this line actually works.
```